# Keeping Red Zone Stats

Tags: american-football, statistics

If a team enters the red zone and then gets sacked out of the red zone. On the next play they get into the redzone again. Then they score on the next play.  Does this mean the team is 1-2 in the red zone or 1-1 in the redzone?